# Upgrading Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 failed and won't boot

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 18.04

When I tried to update Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04, the installation failed and stopped the update. Now it won't boot. How can I fix Ubuntu and save my files that are on the computer?

Comment: Honestly, you need to give a lot more information than this if you want some useful advice.  Based on the limited information you've given, I can suggest you give BootRepair a try:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair .  This is a first step of many but hopefully it will get you started.

Comment: First thing I would do is boot with a Live USB and copy the `/home` directory to another disk or USB pen drive. Many times people make things worse in the process of "fixing" things.

Comment: If "the installation failed" for other reasons (i.e. was not interrupted), then 1) Create a new 18.04 LiveUSB. 2) Boot using the LiveUSB and preserve all your files to a different media. 3) Clean-intall using the LiveUSB.